# Tips for "Tower of Goo" level in "World of Goo"

Tags: world-of-goo

I'm having a lot of problems just getting through Tower of Goo level in the first chapter, nevermind getting the OCD (which I won't even try). Even watching videos on YouTube does not help. No matter how closely I attempt to follow what the videos do, the tower keeps falling over.

Does anyone have hints or walkthroughs on how to get through this level? Or, perhaps generic tips for World of Goo -- I might be missing something important?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This isn't a level you should be looking to score a lot of extra goo balls on.  Build out your base to 5 or 6 goo balls across.  Go up a few levels, and then bring it in by one goo ball.  Continue this process, while maintaining strength by adding goo balls to whichever side your tower is leaning to in a truss structure.  Once you're within about 3-5 meters, build up as fast as you can.  The suction from the pipe will help to keep your tower stable, and you should be able to stop building.  With any luck, you'll still have more than 25 goo balls left to complete the level.